# Converting matplotlib chart to interactive chart in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, ipywidgets

I have a Matplotlib stacked bar plot -

```
df.groupby(['date', 'flavor'])['minutes'].sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

I would like to convert this to an interactive plot using `interact` from `ipywidgets`. But, when I try this -

```
@interact
df.groupby(['date', 'flavor'])['minutes'].sum().unstack().iplot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

It gives me an `Exception: Invalid keyword : 'stacked'`. Can someone tell me the right syntax for this kind of interactive chart with `ipywidgets`?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using %matplotlib notebook, this activates nbagg backend which enables interactivity see this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_1.4.html#the-nbagg-backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! It's an attribute called `barmode`. So, it can used as -

```
@interact
df.groupby(['date', 'flavor'])['minutes'].sum().unstack().iplot(kind='bar', barmode='stack')
```